# What is the difference between mono and mono develop?

Tags: mono, monodevelop

i am curious to know what exactly is the difference between Mono Software and Monodevelop. and do i need both of these if i want to do "C#"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- mono

  is the **runtime** that executes your interpreted code.
- monodevelop

  is an **IDE** (Intergrated Development Enviroment) it helps you write, evaluate and debug code written in VB, C#, etc. that eventually gets executed by the mono runtime.

While you need `mono`, you don't *need* `monodevelop` to write and execute C# applications. However, it is quite a nice IDE to write C# and it takes some of the labour out of debugging.

Comment: The answer could be clearer if it were to explain IDE